# Laravel 5.3 dynamic routing to multiple controllers

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.3. I have a bunch of urls that I'd like to handle with a single route, to multiple controllers.

e.g.

```
GET /admin/foo => FooController@index
GET /admin/foo/edit/1 => FooController@edit($id)
GET /admin/bar => BarController@index
GET /admin/bar/edit/1 => BarController@item($id)
GET /admin/baz => BazController@index
GET /admin/baz/edit/1 => BazController@item($id)
etc.
```

I want to be able to detect if the controller exists, and if not throw a 404 or route to a default controller (which may throw a 404).

Below is what I've got so far, but I'm not sure what I'm doing. Shouldn't I be instantiating the controller using the service container? I don't think I should be hardcoding namespaces like this. And my handling of the id parameter is sketchy. Perhaps I should have two routes for these two patterns or something?

```
Route::get('/admin/{entityType}/{action?}/{id?}', function ($entityType, $action = 'index', $id = null) {

    $controllerClass = 'App\Http\Controllers\\' . ucfirst($entityType) . 'Controller';
    $controller = new $controllerClass;

    $route = app(\Illuminate\Routing\Route::class);
    $container = app(\Illuminate\Container\Container::class);
    return (new Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher($container))->dispatch($route, $controller, $action);

    abort(404);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to define a route for every controller explicitly. This is the best way to build a maintainable app.

Also, if using one route and one method is an option (with right architecure it is) use one route:

```
Route::get('/admin/{entityType}/{action?}/{id?}', 'Controller@method');
```

And one entry point:

```
public function method($entity, $action = null, $id = null)
{
    // Handle request here.
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#parameters-optional-parameters